# ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate has null person object

Tags: addressbook, ios9

I know that AB framework is deprecated in iOS 9 but I have some unexpected behavior in the **ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate** - the **newPersonViewController:didCompleteWithNewPerson:** selector returns a nil *person* even if the use pressed Save.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate_Protocol/

I am using Xcode 7 beta6 with an iPhone running iOS9 beta5. Funny enough the issue doesn't occur in the iOS9 simulator (latest beta).
And of course doesn't occur for any iOS8 and early devices.

Anyone encoutered this issue ?

[ Posted also in https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/45553 ]

Comment: I am running into the same issue on Xcode 7 and iOS 9.0.1

Comment: @mike.tihonchik - is related with Exchange, check if your default contact group is an Exchange server, if yes, switch it to something else and will work